# web2py server stops responding when assigning the id from an INSERT query to variable

Tags: web2py, vscode-debugger

I am using the latest version of Vscode. I have a break point on the line below. It is the only line in my controller:

```
db.CardMasters.insert(Name='please work your killing me')
```

It works fine - a new record is inserted into the table. But if i change that line to:

```
newid = db.CardMasters.insert(Name='please work your killing me')
```

web2py hangs and I need to restart the server. I have tried the same action on a few tables with the same result.

If I don't try to step through the code it sometimes works fine. Where should I start looking for a fix for this?

Model

```
db.define_table(
    'CardMasters',
    Field('Name'),
    Field('Categories'),
    Field('Description'),
    singular="Card Master", plural="Card Masters",
    format = '%(Name)s (%(Description)s)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i upgraded to the latest version of web2py and my problem went away. I wish i had thought of that earlier!